# How to replace Div elements with dynamically generated elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div structure like this

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="dvInsert">
    // insert dynamic generated elements 
</div>
```

I am decoding HTML elements and want to append to existing div but its showing div structure in browser like this:

```
     <div class="col-md-12">
         <p>Hello this is my new paragraph</p>
     </div>


function htmlDecode(value) {

         $("#dvInsert").append($('<div/>').html(value).text());
     }
```

I have also tried this but its also shwoing div strcuture rather then text.

```
 $($('<div/>').html(value).text()).appendTo("#dvInsert");
```

Value of value is `&amp;lt;div class="row"&amp;gt;&lt;div&gt;&amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;div class="col-md-12"&amp;gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Hello this is my new paragraph&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;&lt;/div&gt;`

Comment: What do you mean, you're creating a DIV and inserting it, what do you expect ?

Comment: I am creating div and inserting inside div @adeneo

Comment: why do you call .text()? If you want add `<div>` with html you should call only `$('<div/>').html(value)`

Comment: @Alesh I am decoding string. I have encoded it first then I am decoding it and inserting in div

Comment: @aa003 ok, but decoding of html string happens by `.html(value)` which sets html of `$('<div/>')` to html in `value` variable. `.text()` just returns inner text of given element, which is content of `value`

Answer (score 0):

What goes inside `.append` as parameter should be an jquery object. In your case, you are already creating an object with this: `$('<div/>').html(value)`. You just need to discard `.text()`. In short, you need to change this

```
$('<div/>').html(value).text()
```

to

```
$('<div/>').html(value)
```

Comment: without .text it gives encoded string `&lt;div class="row"&gt;<div>&nbsp; &nbsp;&lt;div class="col-md-12"&gt;</div><div>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&lt;p&gt;Hello this is my new paragraph&lt;/p&gt;</div><div>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;</div><div>&lt;/div&gt;</div>`?

Comment: @aa003 what is the vaue of `value`

Answer (score 0):

My Friend Hope you have to just replace the existing div you can try something like this below

```
$("#div1").replaceWith("<div>I'm new!</div>");
```

For more details about replace with [Read](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to run it twice:

```
var escaped1 = $('<div/>').html(value).text();
var escaped2 = $('<div/>').html(escaped1).text();

$("#dvInsert").append($(escaped2));
```

but I'm sure that there is a better way...